# Sort files (including those in subdirectories) based on their size and print file name and size

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Need to sort the files based on their size and print only size and file name (no path).

I tried with the following command to achieve this,

> find . -type f  -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h

But this prints the result like this,

```
6.0K ~/Documents/Folder/B/File2.txt

6.0K ~/Documents/Folder/KK/KB/File12.txt 

4.0K ~/Documents/Folder/A/File1.txt
```

But I'm expecting the output to get printed with file name without directory prefix like,

```
6.0K File2.txt

6.0K File12.txt

4.0K File1.txt
```

Note: All file names in my directory are with unique names and there will not be any duplicate file name in my case. I'm not sure how to achieve this result. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `-r` is a reverse sort, but that doesn't match the output I'm seeing. Also, do you need it in `-h`uman-readable format, or could it maybe be bytes?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @PaulHodges. The results were in descending order but while writing it here I made a mistake by writing it in ascending order. And I need the output to be in `h`uman readable format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to accomplish it with `awk`:

```
find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h | awk '{sub(".*\/","",$2)}1'
```

It just keep the final word after `/`

`awk` separates lines by spaces, in your case:

```
$1         $2    

6.0K      ~/Documents/Folder/B/File2.txt

6.0K      ~/Documents/Folder/KK/KB/File12.txt 

4.0K      ~/Documents/Folder/A/File1.tx
```

So, as you want to preserve the first column, you just to apply the regex(`.*\/`) to second column. That regex match to everything up to slash,(I use `\/` because you need to escape `/`). Then, I replace that regex match with `''`(deletes it basically).

Comment: Deletes(Replace for `''`) absolute path, except final part.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you :) What does `1` at the end does in `awk {}1`?

Comment: I use it to print the line

Answer (score 3):

`find`'s `printf` function can report the file sizes while it's doing the search, and the names without the path. It can even do all sort of formatting to support neat columns if you like.

```
find $PWD -printf "%10.10s\t%f\n" | sort -n
```

%s is bytes. %k would list size in KB.

It's all in the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

I know that isn't the same as the output of `du -h`, sorry, but you may save a ton of time by skipping all those process invocations....

Comment: It's working fine with `linux` machines. But when I try with my mac it says like, `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`. Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Comment: Check your version. You might be able to [install a GNU equivalent](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/)?

Answer (score 1):

The du command outputs with \t, so you can use 2 delimiters (`\t,/`) in awk

```
> find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h | awk -F"[\t/]" ' { print $1,$NF } '
4.0K sameer.pkg
0 rem_col_rows.pl
0 rem_col_rows.dat
0 myfile
>
```

EDIT:

To get as csv...

```
> find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h | awk -F"[\t/]" ' { print $1,$NF } ' | tr ' ' ',' | tr '\n' ','
4.0K,sameer.pkg,0,skip_lines.txt,0,rem_col_rows.pl,0,rem_col_rows.dat,0,paras.txt,0,myfile,0,foo.yaml2,0,foo.yaml,
```

EDIT2

```
find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h | awk -F"[\t/]" ' { print $1,$NF } ' | tr ' ' ',' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g'
```

EDIT3

```
> find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h | awk -F"[\t/]" ' { printf("%s,%s\n",$1,$NF) } '
4.0K,sameer.pkg
0,skip_lines.txt
0,rem_col_rows.pl
0,rem_col_rows.dat
0,paras.txt
0,myfile
0,foo.yaml2
0,foo.yaml
>
```

Comment: Is there any way to print the output like, `4.0K , sameer.pkg` , `0 , rem_col_rows.pl` - so this could be exported as a csv too..

Comment: yes.. just pipe it with ````tr```` command and convert the ````\n```` to comma

Comment: check my EDIT to the answer

Comment: With the EDIT the entire result is coming as an output in a single file. How to print without loosing new line character that we got in the previous result?

Comment: just remove the second piping  tr '\n' ','

Comment: By removing the second piping, that brings something like - `,16K,abc.py` an extra `,` at the front for few cases..

Comment: just pipe it again to ````  sed 's/,$//g'  ```` to remove that

Comment: Nop ! It doesn't @stack0114106

Comment: could you please paste the full command in the question again?. let me check

Comment: find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h | awk -F"[\t/]" ' { print $1,$NF } ' | tr ' ' ',' | tr '\n' ',' | ```` sed 's/,$//g' ````

Comment: oh.. sorry! I added the backticks for SO editing ..check my answer at the last

Comment: It's okay @stack0114106

Comment: find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h | awk -F"[\t/]" ' { print $1,$NF } ' | tr ' ' ',' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g'

Comment: I tried removing the backslashes now on `sed` but even now I'm not able to get it ..

Comment: you want it in single line?.. or multiple line

Comment: I want it in multiple lines as we got it previously !

Comment: check my EDIT3.. I just pasted with the output I got.. you can do it with awk itself..